# Is my Homebrew race Lugvian balanced?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew-review

Ability Score Increase. Constitution 2+

Size. Standing 4'4 your size is medium

Speed. You have a walking speed of 10 feet.

Natural Armor. You have an AC of 15 regardless of your DEX modifer.

True Sight. You have truesight for 50 feet and are blind beyond this.

Energy Cannon. You have a mounted cannon on your arm. It cannot be removed unless you are incapitated. It does 1d12 radiant damage. This increases to 2d12 at lvl 9, 3d12 at lvl 15.(Range 10/50)

Languages: You can speak read and write common.

Comment: If someone needs to contact me please use @RandomPerson. This is my phone account. I couldn't figure out how to login to my other account.

Comment: 10/50 range. And plz contact me with @RandomPerson.

Comment: Please review our meta guidelines that have been provided to you before about how to present and ask for balance of homebrew. Have you made any effort to balance/compare this yourself? Also the asker of a question is automatically given a notification when a comment is made on their question. Additionally using @randomperson will not notify that account unless it has already made a comment on here. I'd suggest attempting to [merge the accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) and figuring out how to log into your other account.

Comment: Can this race wear armor at all or is 15 constant? Do you know that 10 speed is not an option in any playable race? How do you use the cannon, does it require an action? What about a free hand?

Comment: Hello. Have you seen [this meta post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8121/10642)? If no, please do so.

Comment: You have also posted 3 different homebrew reviews, none of which have gone through our requested Meta process. I'm voting to close this until we have the information from our meta direction included. I'd also highly recommend doing some more personal review before posting here. Your review requests read very much like first drafts. You should be confident in your own homebrew balance before coming here. The stack is here to help, but you need to show some effort as well.

Comment: We can’t contact you @RandomPerson because the site doesn’t allow contacting just anyone anywhere. It only allows contacting the post author + people already commenting under the post. You can fix it by [following these instructions for merging accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts). All your posts will be in the same account then, and you’ll be able to access it from all your devices.

Answer (score 5):

### Not balanced, far too restrictive

The ability score increase is unusual. No class relies on constitution as its primary ability but it is commonly the most important secondary attribute. I'd say this is on the weaker side as one loses the specialization bonuses granted by other races' ability bonuses.

The speed of 10 feet per turn is abysmal and will result in turns spent waiting to get into range. It shoehorns this race towards a ranged playstyle, but unfortunately even that will be problematic because the character is blind beyond the first 50 feet. Playing this race I would be tempted to pick the Monk class just to eventually get better mobility, but the natural defense feature synergizes poorly with Monk AC.

Truesight is way too powerful as an innate racial ability. The spell *True Seeing* is the usual way to get it and it is a sixth level spell. See also this question that concerns the power of Truesight: [How powerful would an always-on Truesight ability be for a PC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/137172/how-powerful-would-an-always-on-truesight-ability-be-for-a-pc/137177#137177)

The energy cannon is poorly defined. What does one roll to attack with it? Does it prevent the character from using their hand, further shoehorning them into very specific playstyles? Is the PC proficient with it? The damage output is swingy and falls behind other options soon after the first level, which wouldn't necessarily be a problem for an extra ranged attack given as a tactical option, but the attack has such abysmal range it's probably not as good as you think. The radiant damage can offer some neat situational advantages, though, as it often deals extra damage or triggers special effects against undead.

### Conclusion

This feels like a very classic case of a gimmick race that simply lacks the typical flexibility that allows an interesting variety of gameplay. It has such severe limitations that it is heavily discouraged from taking most classes, forcing the player taking it into the confines of a very particular playstyle. I would discourage enforcing a very particular strategy even for a homebrew class, and emphatetically so for races.

Comment: There's also truesight via Epic Boons (see [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/137177/35259)), which further reasserts that truesight is way too powerful as an innate racial ability.

Comment: @NathanS Thanks, I incorporated this into my answer

Comment: What if I increase sight to 90 and replace truesight with blind sight

Comment: @Demi-Devil Considering the race's other major issues... it'd be better but still not good. If you want to ask follow-up questions, check out this guide: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8122/11660